# Wiki answers without revision are missing the link to author's profile

Tags: bug, community-wiki

On every Wiki-answer post that doesn't have an edit, clicking the author's username links to the first revision, instead of the user's profile.

Take example of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/469412/5468463) answer.
The click on the post author's name, gives the correct access to the [user's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/154560/matthew-taylor), while the click on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/326529/5468463) author's name, gives access to the post [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/326529/revisions), instead of the user's profile, as would be expected.

This is valid for the main SO and meta sites.

As a quick track for finding the bug, I have the following.

- For the posts with revision(s), as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/469412/5468463), the href attribute on the anchor is set correctly, (although there is an invalid anchor nesting, as noted by Heretic Monkey in comments), i.e. to the user's profile:

[image]

- Whilst [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/301136/5468463), a post without revision, a click on the user's name ends up on the revision page because of the misleading anchor:

[image]

The latter is an incoherence, a bug, and needs to be corrected.

This is going on for at least three and half years. Can it be fixed now?

Comment: It's actually invalid to nest anchors with hrefs in HTML... The second anchor, linking to the user's profile, should be outside the anchor to the revisions.

Comment: "*the click links to the first revision*" The click? Did you mean some other word? What is the click?

Comment: Tyler I meant literally a click, the action of clicking on the user's name. Maybe the word "links" is misleading? I meant "opening". I expect that click on user's name would open user's profile page, not the revision

Comment: @Vega Thanks, it was unclear what HTML entity you were clicking when you said 'the click'.

Comment: While the HTML is, obviously, messed up, linking to the /revisions page under these conditions has been the case [since at least 2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20100224004453/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300855/looking-for-a-better-javascript-unit-test-tool/301136). Interestingly, it [was not the case in 2009](https://web.archive.org/web/20090211214912/http://stackoverflow.com:80/questions/300855?sort=newest), but there was a notably different post footer in 2009. So, just the fact that the username links to the post's /revisions page appears to be [meta-tag:status-bydesign].

Comment: As to the invalid HTML (e.g., the `<a>2 revs, 2 users 86%<a>Matthew Taylor</a></a>`), that appears to have been resolved since 2020, as the two links are distinct at this point.